# Prestashop deos not reflect global.css changes

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to put background image in my store. 
I edit global.css file I set Performance Force Compilation = true and cache =no.
I change color of body 
I put background image 
like below

```
body{

    font:normal 11px/14px Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;

    color:#555;


    background:#555 url('../img/flowerbg114.gif')repeat
    background-size: contain
}
```

But nothing changes in my front office :(

My img file is under img folder under the selected theme..

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Make sure there is a space before the `repeat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the theme I was using was probably overriding some of the style changes. I found out that it has a module which helps to set some properties like background picture or store logo. When I use the user interface of that module I managed to change the background easily.

Answer (score 0):

try below CSS

```
body {

       font:normal 11px/14px Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;

       color:#555;

       background:url(../img/flowerbg114.gif) #555  repeat;
       background-size: contain;
     }
```

After each line you end, or each css property you complete, place ; .

Check it and it will be working fine now.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you edit header.tpl and change line 40

after `{$HOOK_HEADER} </head>`

from:

```
<body {if $page_name}id="{$page_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"{/if}>
```

to:

```
<body {if $page_name}id="{$page_name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"{/if} style="background:url({$img_dir}page/background{math equation='rand(1, 6)'}.png) repeat-x top center">
```

This should select a random number between 1 and then load the background image with that number in the filename. Just create `background1.png`, `background2.png`, etc.

**Note**: will override the body tag in `global.css`.

Make a file name of a page, and then put the pictures inside
Annexation place the file in img Directory